# How to run Kivy on Debian Jessie?

Tags: python, linux, numpy, kivy

I installed Kivy on Debian Jessie following [the instructions on their website.](http://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-linux.html#debian-jessie-or-newer) Everything installed smoothly. But whenever I try to run any Kivy example, or even my own Kivy code, I get the following output:

```
[INFO   ] Kivy v1.8.0
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/tom/.kivy/logs/kivy_14-12-10_3.txt
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 157 symbols loaded
[DEBUG  ] [Cache       ] register <kv.lang> with limit=None, timeout=Nones
[DEBUG  ] [Cache       ] register <kv.image> with limit=None, timeout=60s
[DEBUG  ] [Cache       ] register <kv.atlas> with limit=None, timeout=Nones
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_pygame, img_pil, img_gif 
[DEBUG  ] [Cache       ] register <kv.texture> with limit=1000, timeout=60s
[DEBUG  ] [Cache       ] register <kv.shader> with limit=1000, timeout=3600s
[DEBUG  ] [Window      ] Ignored <egl_rpi> (import error)
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: pygame(['window_egl_rpi'] ignored)
nvc0_screen_create:660 - Error creating SW object: -22
*** Error in `python': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0000000002414c90 ***
Aborted
```

If you are familiar with Kivy you'll know all that output is fine except for this part:

```
nvc0_screen_create:660 - Error creating SW object: -22
*** Error in `python': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0000000002414c90 ***
Aborted
```

I did some googling and found that this has to do with memory leaks, or calling `free()` somewhere you're not supposed to. However, this obviously has nothing to do with the Python code. Some results turned up similar problems with NumPy and SciPy, but both seem to be fully updated.

If you want any more information about my OS or hardware, I'd be glad to post. Just ask.

How can I get rid of this error and run Kivy?

Comment: It looks like you're using software rendering? Don't know if that would cause this problem, but performance will be subpar. There have also been issues in the past with Nouveau rendering incorrectly.

Comment: @Ryan I don't think I'm using software rendering.

Comment: You might try asking on our IRC channel #kivy on freenode.